# Fill conditional formatting in VBA is not working

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

Here's my problem.  There are two conditional formatting sections in the code below.  The first one highlights the cells red, and the second highlights the cells orange.  When I run this code, it highlights the second conditional formatting yellow and does not apply any fill to the first conditional formatting.  When I watch code run line by line, the first section appears to work but then it change the fill to orange in the first conditional formatting section and it doesn't apply any fill to the second section.

```
Sub ConditionalFormat()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("CSR")
lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


With Range("N10:AN" & lRow)
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=AND(N10>=($AR10-7),N10>0)"
    .FormatConditions(Range("N10:AN" & lRow).FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Range("N10:AN" & lRow).FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
End With
Range("N10:AN" & lRow).FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
With Range("V10:V" & lRow)
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=AND($N10<=($V10-35),N10>0,$C10>0)"
    '.FormatConditions(Range("V10:V" & lRow).FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Range("V10:V" & lRow).FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 10284031
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
Range("V10:V" & lRow).FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub`
```

Comment: All of your Range() and Cells() calls really need to be qualified with the `ws` worksheet reference.

Comment: Because your second range is contained within the first range, the results are what you are experiencing.  If your first range did not reference column V your results will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer but wanted to suggest you simplify your code so you can concentrate on the actual issue a bit more easily:

```vb
Sub ConditionalFormat()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("CSR")
    
    lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    AddFormulaCF ws.Range("N10:AN" & lRow), _
                "=AND(N10>=($AR10-7),N10>0)", _
                13551615
    
    AddFormulaCF ws.Range("N10:AN" & lRow), _
                "=AND($N10<=($V10-35),N10>0,$C10>0)", _
                10284031

End Sub

'Apply a formula-based CF fill to a range
Sub AddFormulaCF(rng As Range, frm As String, clr As Long)
    ' `.Add()` returns the added FormatCondition, so you can work directly with that.
    With rng.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=frm)
        .SetFirstPriority
        .StopIfTrue = False
        With .Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = clr
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Tim, thank you for the suggestion.  I copied in this code verbatim and it had an error at the "With rng.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpession..." line.  The error was "Invalid procedure call or argument". Is that because the code doesn't set statement for rng, frm, and clr?

Comment: That code works "verbatim" for me - rng, frm and clr are provided as arguments when the call is made to the sub `AddFormulaCF`